# What is this pair of rectangular patterns on the Enterprise-D's exterior?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

On the Enterprise-D's exterior hull, a little underneath the main shuttle bay, there are a pair of rectangles made up of smaller rectangles with gaps in the middle. In many shots, they are glowing bluish.

What are they supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: It's the number of lives remaining.  They've got to be careful now; if they lose this one before they earn another bonus life, it's game over.

Comment: To me they look like they could be the impulse engines of the saucer section glowing with some exotic type of energy.  If those a windows and the blue light is the normal light in the arboretum shining, people in the aboretum may be likely to get sunburns and skin cancer, or even radiaiton poisoning.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: The saucer section impulse engines glow red, and are more lateral. See [this image](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic1.wikia.nocookie.net%2F__cb20130216211133%2Fmemoryalpha%2Fen%2Fimages%2F2%2F21%2FGalaxy_class_impulse_engines.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) (where they're more yellowish).

Comment: @M.A.GoldingThe large cutouts in the saucer rim at the top and bottom of the image contain the saucer's impulse engines.

Comment: This needs more hand-drawn red circles

Comment: @Valorum: I thought about doing that, but didn't want to spoil the image :-\

Comment: Skylights over the swimming pool heated by spent fuel rods.

Comment: @M.A.Golding If those were impulse engines, Starfleet has no hope.

Answer (score 29):

The [*Star Trek: The Next Generation USS Enterprise NCC-1701-D Blueprints*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_USS_Enterprise_NCC-1701-D_Blueprints) set says they're the windows of the arboretum.

[image]

Comment: In my head I questioned this answer: "official? Says who?". Looks like it is indeed 'official' but with a caveat that a different project usurped this one so it's not necessarily official. Still - +1 from me. More details here - https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/ed-whitefire-enterprise-ncc-1701d.php

Comment: "*Some blueprints have identified the two large blue windows below the main shuttlebay on the Enterprise-D model as the arboretum windows, although the set had no such windows. It is possible there was more than one arboretum on the Galaxy-class. Also the arboretum is stated to be on Deck 17, however that was the ship's stardrive section, where most of the ship's essential functions were located. Blueprints produced by Rick Sternbach show the twin windows for the arboretum however interior blue prints do not show them.*" - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arboretum

Comment: I've updated this to a Memory Alpha link so that people can judge the relative canonicity of the blueprints.

Comment: @Valorum - is the image linked actually from the published blueprints book? The info on the Cygnus site from the original answer indicates that the book blueprints were changed from what is shown on the site

Comment: @NKCampbell - I think there were some minor changes, but this page was untouched from the original. Note that the version on Cygnus is mostly thumbnails to prevent accusations of copyright fraud

Comment: I don't remember the arboretum having anything like those kind of windows. Also, how would this explain the central rectangle being missing in each larger-rectangle? No-Window above another window and below another window? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @einpoklum My best guess is grow lights... really, really big grow lights. While they always show plenty of light inside the ship, in the vast majority of cases, it's really, really dark outside - starships spend a great deal of time between star systems, away from any source of exterior illumination. You arrange them like that so the light comes from roughly the same direction, whether it's purely artificial or natural-augmented (you'd never turn the artificial light completely off, but you could balance it against exterior light).

Comment: @T.J.L.: 1. But this doesn't explain the dark rectangle in the middle. 2. No sense for the grow-light to involve a window into space (which obviously would be hidden from the inside.

Comment: @einpoklum Indeed, why would an arboretum on a spaceship need windows *at all*?  On a planet, sure, you want windows to let in sunlight, but in deep space, there isn't going to be significant sunlight most of the time, so the windows aren't all that useful.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman so those taking a romantic walk through the arboretum can look out at the "night" sky?

Comment: @FreeMan See, I'd just replace those windows with a couple giant flat-panel displays (just like the one they have on the Bridge, so we know they have the tech) and have it play scenery, so you can take a romantic walk in the daytime too if you want...

Comment: @einpoklum It was mostly a joke, but the implication is that the dark rectangle is where the lights are mounted... you know... with no window behind the lights.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Why have windows anywhere on the ship at all then? Perhaps because sometimes people like to know what they're seeing is unedited and real, not a screen.

Comment: @T.J.L.: But in the arboretum, the intended ambient effect is that of day-time. (Well, except when it's night-time for the flora to enjoy that part of the day.)

Comment: Seeing this claim more explicitly also in [this diagram](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/galaxy-08.jpg).